# Find first and last non-zero column in each row of a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, argmax

I have DataFrame in view of `Name` and `Date` with values of weight in cells :

```
Name        Jan17  Jun18  Dec18    Apr19  count 
Nick         0      1.7     3.7      0     2
Jack         0       0      2.8     3.5    2       
Fox          0      1.7      0       0     1
Rex          1.0     0      3.0     4.2    3
Snack        0       0      2.8     4.4    2
Yosee        0       0       0      4.3    1 
Petty        0.5    1.3     2.8     3.5    4
```

`Start` and `Finish` should be added to the dataFrame in reference to the next definition:

1. `Start` first non zero value in row started from `Jan17`
   column to `Apr19`
2. `Finish` first non zero value in
   sequence `Apr19` till to `Jan17`

Also, if row has only one non-zero value in row then `Start` and`Finish`  are the same.

To find first non zero element in row I tried `data[col].keys, np.argmax()` and it works as expected.

`date_col_list = ['Jan17','Jun18','Dec18', 'Apr19']`

`data['Start']=data[date_col_list].keys([np.argmax(data[date_col_list].values!=0, axis=1)]`

Result is:

```
Name        Jan17  Jun18  Dec18    Apr19  count   Start 
Nick         0      1.7     3.7      0     2      Jun18        
Jack         0       0      2.8     3.5    2      Dec18           
Fox          0      1.7      0       0     1      Jun18    
Rex          1.0     0      3.0     4.2    3      Jan18    
Snack        0       0      2.8     4.4    2      Dec18    
Yosee        0       0       0      4.3    1      Apr19     
Petty        0.5    1.3     2.8     3.5    4      Jan17
```

To detect values for `Finish` column I tried to use:
`np.apply_along_axis` as:
`def func_X(i):`
      `return np.argmax(np.where(i!=0))`

`np.apply_along_axis(func1d = func_X, axis=1, arr=data[date_col_list].values)`

Result is error:
`'tuple' object has no attribute 'argmax'`

Expected dataframe is:

```
Name        Jan17  Jun18  Dec18    Apr19  count   Start  Finish
Nick         0      1.7     3.7      0     2      Jun18   Dec18     
Jack         0       0      2.8     3.5    2      Dec18   Apr19        
Fox          0      1.7      0       0     1      Jun18   Jun18 
Rex          1.0     0      3.0     4.2    3      Jan18   Apr19 
Snack        0       0      2.8     4.4    2      Dec18   Apr19 
Yosee        0       0       0      4.3    1      Apr19   Apr19  
Petty        0.5    1.3     2.8     3.5    4      Jan17   Apr19
```

How can I find `Finish` in reference to non-zero value in direction from the last column (`Apr19`) to the first one (`Jan17`)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### `first_valid_index` and `last_valid_index`

```
d = df.mask(df == 0).drop(['Name', 'count'], 1)
df.assign(
    Start=d.apply(pd.Series.first_valid_index, 1),
    Finish=d.apply(pd.Series.last_valid_index, 1)
)

    Name  Jan17  Jun18  Dec18  Apr19  count  Start Finish
0   Nick    0.0    1.7    3.7    0.0      2  Jun18  Dec18
1   Jack    0.0    0.0    2.8    3.5      2  Dec18  Apr19
2    Fox    0.0    1.7    0.0    0.0      1  Jun18  Jun18
3    Rex    1.0    0.0    3.0    4.2      3  Jan17  Apr19
4  Snack    0.0    0.0    2.8    4.4      2  Dec18  Apr19
5  Yosee    0.0    0.0    0.0    4.3      1  Apr19  Apr19
6  Petty    0.5    1.3    2.8    3.5      4  Jan17  Apr19
```

---

#### `stack` then `groupby`

```
d = df.mask(df == 0).drop(['Name', 'count'], 1)
def fl(s): return s.xs(s.name).index[[0, -1]]
s, f = d.stack().groupby(level=0).apply(fl).str
df.assign(Start=s, Finish=f)

    Name  Jan17  Jun18  Dec18  Apr19  count  Start Finish
0   Nick    0.0    1.7    3.7    0.0      2  Jun18  Dec18
1   Jack    0.0    0.0    2.8    3.5      2  Dec18  Apr19
2    Fox    0.0    1.7    0.0    0.0      1  Jun18  Jun18
3    Rex    1.0    0.0    3.0    4.2      3  Jan17  Apr19
4  Snack    0.0    0.0    2.8    4.4      2  Dec18  Apr19
5  Yosee    0.0    0.0    0.0    4.3      1  Apr19  Apr19
6  Petty    0.5    1.3    2.8    3.5      4  Jan17  Apr19
```

Answer (score 7):

## `idxmax`

```
mask = df.drop(['Name', 'count'], axis=1) > 0
df.assign(start=mask.idxmax(axis=1), end=mask.iloc[:,::-1].idxmax(axis=1))

    Name  Jan17  Jun18  Dec18  Apr19  count  start    end
0   Nick    0.0    1.7    3.7    0.0      2  Jun18  Dec18
1   Jack    0.0    0.0    2.8    3.5      2  Dec18  Apr19
2    Fox    0.0    1.7    0.0    0.0      1  Jun18  Jun18
3    Rex    1.0    0.0    3.0    4.2      3  Jan17  Apr19
4  Snack    0.0    0.0    2.8    4.4      2  Dec18  Apr19
5  Yosee    0.0    0.0    0.0    4.3      1  Apr19  Apr19
6  Petty    0.5    1.3    2.8    3.5      4  Jan17  Apr19
```

Drop irrelevant columns, then use `idxmax` first on the columns, then on the reversed columns to find the first and last valid indices respectively.

Answer (score 7):

In your case try something different with `dot`

```
s=df.loc[:,'Jan17':'Apr19'].ne(0)
s=s.dot(s.columns+',').str[:-1].str.split(',')
s.str[0],s.str[-1]
Out[899]: 
(0    Jun18
 1    Dec18
 2    Jun18
 3    Jan17
 4    Dec18
 5    Apr19
 6    Jan17
 dtype: object, 0    Dec18
 1    Apr19
 2    Jun18
 3    Apr19
 4    Apr19
 5    Apr19
 6    Apr19
 dtype: object)
 #df['Start'],df['End']=s.str[0],s.str[-1]
```

Answer (score 6):

Using `cumsum` on the underlying `array`

```
m = df.drop(['Name', 'count'], axis=1)
u = m.to_numpy().cumsum(1)

start = (u!=0).argmax(1)
end = u.argmax(1)

df.assign(start=m.columns[start], end=m.columns[end])
```

```
    Name  Jan17  Jun18  Dec18  Apr19  count  start    end
0   Nick    0.0    1.7    3.7    0.0      2  Jun18  Dec18
1   Jack    0.0    0.0    2.8    3.5      2  Dec18  Apr19
2    Fox    0.0    1.7    0.0    0.0      1  Jun18  Jun18
3    Rex    1.0    0.0    3.0    4.2      3  Jan17  Apr19
4  Snack    0.0    0.0    2.8    4.4      2  Dec18  Apr19
5  Yosee    0.0    0.0    0.0    4.3      1  Apr19  Apr19
6  Petty    0.5    1.3    2.8    3.5      4  Jan17  Apr19
```